# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established mongodb compass error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

When I created a cluster and project in mongodb atlas. I tried to connect using mongodb compass. In atlas I was given a link to copy and paste in mongodb compass for connecting. When I clicked connect button,
it is showing the error **client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established**

I tried unabling the proxy and VPN but it didn't work.

What should I do to make the connection.[Mongodb compass error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G8Qc.jpg)

I tried unabling proxy and VPN in my windows 10 laptop and it is still not working.